# using an auto generated class file with Java11

Tags: java, jar, java-platform-module-system, module-info

I have a class file that was auto generated. Unfortunately it is only a class file, not a class in jar file that hosts a module.

I can analyse the class file using javap. It host - let's say - the class a.b.c.MyClass.
I would like to add

```
requires a.b.c;
```

to a module-info.java of a using application.

How can I make a certain jar file about that class for to put it on the module-path?

Comment: so the actual question is how to create a JAR from a `.class` file?

Comment: yes. in a way that it is accepted as a module. Should I compile a module-info.java for it - or something like that - e.g. have a dummy class compiled that I replace by the auto generated one?